# Angular Material Dialog close not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular Material and trying to close a dialog window using `mat-dialog-close` but it is not working for some reason.

I saw some questions online and I have `BrowserAnimationModule`, `MatDialogModule` in the `NgModule`.

I am attaching the code, any help is appreciated.

**ModalDialog.html**

```
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-container">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>{{ data }}</h1>
</div>
```

**Register.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { states } from '../constants/states';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  // Fn to open the modal for consent form
  openModal() {
    this.dialog.open(ModalDialog, {
      data: `Some random Data`    
   });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}

// Modal code from angular material
@Component({
  selector: 'modal-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'ModalDialog.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
})
export class ModalDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: string) {}
}
```

**register.html**

```
<div class="row-five">
  <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
  <p>
    I have read this
    <span
      (click)="openModal()"
      style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer"
    >consent form</span
    >
    and I fully understand the contents of this document and voluntarily
    consent to participate in this camp*
  </p>
</div>
```

**Edit**
Versioning of libraries.

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

**Edit**
I did try to use it as an element.

```
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
<div class="modal-container">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>{{ data }}</h1>
</div>
```

I got an error saying this.

```
'mat-dialog-actions' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-dialog-actions' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-dialog-actions' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)
```

Comment: Please add version of material package

Comment: I added all the dependencies. ^-^

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) `mat-dialog-actions` is an element and not an attribute.

Have you tried to use it like below?

```html
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
<div class="modal-container">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>{{ data }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I got an error saying that this is an unknown element, also I believe we can use it as attributes same `<input mat-input />`. I have included the error in the question.

Comment: have you imported the MatDialogModule into the NgModule that these files are under?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have a separate `material.module.ts` that I have included in the `app.module.ts`. I have mentioned this in the question too.